# Why isn't the ending period showing up?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to make a function that takes an array and turns its contents into a string sentence.

```
def sentence_maker(array) 


    clone = array # making a copy of array
    array = array.drop(1) # dropping the first element
    array = array.unshift(clone[0].capitalize) # inserting a capitalized version of the first element of the clone

   array.each do |element|

       print element.to_s + ' ' # a space after each word

   end

   array = array.unshift # remove the space at the end of the last word
   array = array << '.' # inserting a period at the end of the array


end

sentence_maker(['i', 'am', 'awesome'])
```

My rspec returns:

```
expected: "All my socks are dirty."
            got: ["All", "my", "socks", "are", "dirty", "."]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the elements of the array in the `each` loop but you are not creating/returning a new `String`.

A cleaner approach is below:

```
array = ['i', 'am', 'awesome']
array[0] = array[0].capitalize
array.join(" ").concat(".") # => "I am awesome."
```

Comment: Wow! This is beautiful! My method was so bulky. Thanks so much!

Comment: What about `['i', 'am', 'awesome'].join(' ').concat('.').capitalize`! :)

Comment: @maaachine your suggestion might not work in this case: `["I", "AM", "AWESOME"].join(' ').concat('.').capitalize
=> "I am awesome."`, it should be `"I AM AWESOME."` maintaining the character cases, since the OP only wants the first word capitalize

Comment: @bjhaid Very true! Trying to capitalize sentences functionally is a messy business.